# Prestashop discount to increase total cart price

Tags: php, prestashop-1.7

It's sounds a kind weird but I need to use a Prestashop 1.7 discount based on transportation id = 1 to increase 20% over cart's total.

I don't know where the function is and where to place...

Answer (score 1):

You need to find module. For example Cash on Delivery with fee.